# Magick.NET-Q16-x64.Native.dll not found

Tags: c#, nopcommerce, image-compression, magick.net

I am creating nopCommerce plug-in for image compression using Magick.Net library, I make ImageOptimizer object and when calling LosslessCompress method it gives an error like unable to load dll Magick.NET-Q16-x64.Native.dll or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.

I have found Magick.NET-Q16-x64.Native.dll and when I am trying to add a reference for that it gives an error like reference is invalid or unsupported

```
var file = new FileInfo(filepath);

var optimizer = new ImageOptimizer();

optimizer.LosslessCompress(file);
```

[image: exception example]

I expect no error occurs when LosslessCompress method runs and image is successfully compressed.

Comment: Check the build settings and see if you building for x64

Comment: This is a normal mishap in a plugin scenario, the OS has no chance to find the DLL at runtime.  You have to copy that DLL to a directory where it looks, preferably that is in the main EXE install directory.  Or one of the directories listed in the PATH environment variable.  Or, gack, to c:\windows\system32

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just in case anyone ever has this issue and comes across this question. The answer comes from their GitHub docs - https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/main/docs/CrossPlatform.md